# input text field value returning false

Tags: jquery, ajax, user-input, validation, textinput

I have and html form that I validate using ajax. However, when I want to retrieve the values for state and city, they always return false. I tried everything but I don't know whats going on since every other text field returns it input value. Here is my code

```
<input type="text" id="city" value="City"/>
<input type="text" id="state" value="State"/>
```

And some of the javasctipt

```
 var city = $("#city").val();
 var state = $("#state").val();
```

when I alert the city and state, the return `false`

Comment: can you please make a js fiddle

Comment: nevermind... Turns out that in my validation I had if(city = "") and if(state = "") and I was supposed to have if(city == "") and if(state == "")

Comment: post your all code.. may be the problem exists in other portion

Comment: well its a lot, but if you want to see it you could go to http://misamatch.com/register.php

Comment: @lomas09 its running well my dear. I checked from your stie